# Error in test using from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Tags: django, testing, django-models, tdd, traceback

I am using the django.contrib.auth and came across the following error:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
...EE..
======================================================================
ERROR: test_create (new_way.core.tests.test_models.EmployeeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rg3915/git/my/new_way_project/new_way/core/tests/test_models.py", line 121, in setUp
    comission=180.5
  File "/home/rg3915/git/my/new_way_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 452, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'birthday' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

======================================================================
ERROR: test_has_created_at (new_way.core.tests.test_models.EmployeeTest)
Employee must have automatic created_at
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rg3915/git/my/new_way_project/new_way/core/tests/test_models.py", line 121, in setUp
    comission=180.5
  File "/home/rg3915/git/my/new_way_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 452, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'birthday' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.010s

FAILED (errors=2)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

See my models.

https://gist.github.com/rg3915/1f8094c5e3626ae56386

I suspect this error related to the User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you intended to have the `Employee` model being based on the `Person` abstract model and not the `UserProfile`:

```
class Employee(Person):
    ...
```